# RJS in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rjs

- i have put the following rjs in a controller... but it gives me the following error...

> TypeError: Element.update is not a function

```
   respond_to do |format|
    format.js do
      responds_to_parent do
        render :update do |page|
          page.replace_html 'errorLay', :text => "Page with the same name already exists."
          page.show 'errorLay'
          page.delay(2) do
            page.hide 'errorLay'
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

- so how can i get rid of this error...?

Comment: What is `responds_to_parent`?

Comment: responds_to_parent makes the controller to respond to your parent document (PAGE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it's wrong because you try to use responds_to_parent within a respond_to block.

I don't know if you can mix them. I suggest to try without the respond_to block.
To respond properly to request types you can do like

```
if request.xhr?
  responds_to_parent do
    render :update do |page|
      page.replace_html 'errorLay', :text => "Page with the same name already exists."
      page.show 'errorLay'
      page.delay(2) do
        page.hide 'errorLay'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In this way only responds with js, when was an ajax call.
But i suggest to use rjs file instead rendering from controller.

Answer (score 1):

in your controller only write

```
   render :update do |page|
      page.replace_html 'errorLay', :text => "Page with the same name already exists."
      page.show 'errorLay'
      page.delay(2) do
        page.hide 'errorLay'
      end
    end
```

and whaterver you are using for Ajax `link_to_remote`  or anything else `don't write` `:update=>'some_div'`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've forgotten to include `prototype.js` in your layout.  Make sure you have

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "prototype" %>
```

in the HEAD section of your document layout.

Comment: actually, it works in the separate RJS file (which means that prototype.js is included) but it is not working in controller... :( 
something else is going on here...